# Shairport and Shairport-Sync problem

Tags: audio, wireless, shairplay

I have been trying to use my Pi as an AirPlay receiver for my home stereo system. To do so I first downloaded `shairport` using this tutorial, [How-To: Turn your Raspberry Pi into a AirPlay receiver to stream music from your iPhone](http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-airplay-receiver-to-stream-music-from-your-iphone/).

I was able to successfully connect to the Pi with my iPhone 6 running iOS 9, but only for a brief amount of time each attempt. After further research, I learned that iOS 9 is not compatible with `shairport`. So, I downloaded `shairport-sync`, which is advertised to be compatible with iOS 9, using [this tutorial](http://www.redsilico.com/multiroom-audio-raspberry-pi), but I had the same problems.

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of Shairport Sync. Could I suggest that you follow the guide on Shairport Sync's own README.md file, at https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync.

It should not be disconnecting after a few minutes -- the culprit is often a poor network connection.